# Regex to find NFS filesystems that aren't being mounted with nosuid, except for ones with special needs

Tags: solaris, regular-expression

I have a script that runs the command `mount -v 2>/some/file`, which I then parse with another script using the following regex:

`^.*[\ \t]+type[\ \t]+nfs(?![\ \t]+.*\b(?:nosuid|nosetuid)\b).*`

The problem I am having is this: there are a few NFS mounts that have waivers excluding them from being mounted with `nosuid` (they're Solaris 11 IPS repositories).  Now I need to modify my regex to exclude a known mount...

To provide a point of reference, here's some sample output from `mount -v`:

```
$ mount -v
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0                 on  /                  type  ufs      read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/intr/largefiles/logging/xattr/onerror=panic/dev=840000  on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:35  2013
/devices                          on  /devices           type  devfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4c00000                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
ctfs                              on  /system/contract   type  ctfs     read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4c80001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
proc                              on  /proc              type  proc     read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4c40000                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
mnttab                            on  /etc/mnttab        type  mntfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4cc0001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
swap                              on  /etc/svc/volatile  type  tmpfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/xattr/dev=4d00001                                       on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
objfs                             on  /system/object     type  objfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4d40001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
sharefs                           on  /etc/dfs/sharetab  type  sharefs  read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4d80001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1    on  /lib/libc.so.1     type  lofs     read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=840000                                              on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:31  2013
fd                                on  /dev/fd            type  fd       read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4f00001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:35  2013
swap                              on  /tmp               type  tmpfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/xattr/dev=4d00002                                       on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:38  2013
swap                              on  /var/run           type  tmpfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/xattr/dev=4d00003                                       on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:38  2013
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s7                 on  /export/home       type  ufs      read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/intr/largefiles/logging/xattr/onerror=panic/dev=840007  on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:44  2013
sample-ips:/ips/blargSolaris11.1  on  /blargSolaris11.1  type  nfs      remote/read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/soft/xattr/dev=8c00001                           on  Tue  Sep  10  12:07:46  2013
```

I had tried modifying the regex to exclude the IP's mount based on matching the mount at the beginning of the line like this:

`^(.*|[^sample])[\ \t]+type[\ \t]+nfs(?![\ \t]+.*\b(?:nosuid|nosetuid)\b).*`

But it's not working...

Comment: I don't know about Solaris `mount`, but Linux one can take the `-t` parameter, with which you can restrict the output to file systems of certain type. That could cut your regex down.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're doing with that regular expression but it seems fine to me. It appears to be Perl, so using the GNU version of grep's `-P` switch I used your regex like so:

```
$ column -t mount.txt | \
     grep -vP '^(.*|[^sample])[\ \t]+type[\ \t]+nfs(?![\ \t]+.*\b(?:nosuid|nosetuid)\b).*'
```

#### Example

```
$ column -t mount.txt | \
     grep -vP '^(.*|[^sample])[\ \t]+type[\ \t]+nfs(?![\ \t]+.*\b(?:nosuid|nosetuid)\b).*'
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0                 on  /                  type  ufs      read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/intr/largefiles/logging/xattr/onerror=panic/dev=840000  on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:35  2013
/devices                          on  /devices           type  devfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4c00000                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
ctfs                              on  /system/contract   type  ctfs     read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4c80001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
proc                              on  /proc              type  proc     read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4c40000                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
mnttab                            on  /etc/mnttab        type  mntfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4cc0001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
swap                              on  /etc/svc/volatile  type  tmpfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/xattr/dev=4d00001                                       on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
objfs                             on  /system/object     type  objfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4d40001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
sharefs                           on  /etc/dfs/sharetab  type  sharefs  read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4d80001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:25  2013
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1    on  /lib/libc.so.1     type  lofs     read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=840000                                              on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:31  2013
fd                                on  /dev/fd            type  fd       read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=4f00001                                             on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:35  2013
swap                              on  /tmp               type  tmpfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/xattr/dev=4d00002                                       on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:38  2013
swap                              on  /var/run           type  tmpfs    read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/xattr/dev=4d00003                                       on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:38  2013
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s7                 on  /export/home       type  ufs      read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/intr/largefiles/logging/xattr/onerror=panic/dev=840007  on  Fri  Sep  6   12:10:44  2013
```

You'll notice the line starting with the `sample-ips:/ips/blargSolaris11.1` is being filtered out as you're intending.